# Manager Accounting update/install fails

Tags: software-installation, dependencies, mono

Tried to update manager.io accounting program using Ubuntu Software Center. Update fails with:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

```
manager-accounting: Depends: libmono-wcf3.0-cil (>= 2.6.3) but it is not going to be installed here
```

Now, I cannot open Manager. I Tried re-installing:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libmono-wcf3.0-cil
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package libmono-wcf3.0-cil is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
 libmono-wcf3.0a-cil libmono-cil-dev
E: Package 'libmono-wcf3.0-cil' has no installation candidate
```

So, I tried to install the replacement packages:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libmono-wcf3.0a-cil
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
libmono-wcf3.0a-cil is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

$ sudo apt-get install libmono-cil-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
libmono-cil-dev is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

That not resolving the situation, I reinstalled all dependencies of `libmono-wcf3.0-cil` ([source](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise-updates/libmono-wcf3.0-cil)):

- `libmono-corlib2.0-cil (>= 2.6.3)` – Mono core library (for CLI 2.0)
- `libmono-security2.0-cil (>= 2.6.7)` – Mono Security library (for CLI 2.0)
- `libmono-system-messaging2.0-cil (>= 2.6.3)` – Mono System.Messaging Library (for CLI 2.0)
- `libmono-system-web2.0-cil (>= 2.10.3)` – Mono System.Web Library (for CLI 2.0)
- `libmono-system2.0-cil (>= 2.10.3)` – Mono System libraries (for CLI 2.0)

All return as already installed latest versions.

Any ideas?

Comment: What's your Ubuntu release and what's the output of `apt-cache policy manager-accounting`?